# How do I use Mocha and Chai to prove a function's returned object is a "clone" of the argument supplied as an argument to a function?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

I am new to Chai and testing.

given a function defined in clone.js:

```
function makeClone (objectToClone) {
    return Object.assign({}, objectToClone)
}

module.exports = clone
```

what chai test spec can I use in testClone.js?  ie.:

```
    var expect = require('chai').expect

    describe('clone', function () {  
        var clone = require('./clone.js') 
        it('clone of object', function () {

            expect(clone({a:1, b:2}).to.equal({a:1, b:2}));

        })
    })
```

or:

```
     expect(clone({a: 1, b: 2})).to.be.equal.to({a: 1, b: 2});
```

etc.

I haven't found a good resource yet explaining testing and Chai.  They all seem to assume a lot is already understood.  For example, above I show lines where equal is used as a noun in the chain and as a verb.  Training I have seen give no explanation as to how these chains are built so I guess I am free to assume that either of the above chains are fine.   But apparently both are wrong.

Comment: Official documentation is always a good starting point: https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_equal. Try .to.eql for deep equality.

Comment: The “to”/“be” chaining is optional, for readability https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_language-chains

Comment: Thanks, JBalin.  I should have mentioned that I've already been using the official Chai website that you cite.     Your .to.eql   suggestion worked!  Prior to this I had tried using .to.deep.equal  but without success.

Comment: `deep.equal` should work. Not sure why it didn't work for you.

Comment: Did you see my answer below? If helpful, please accept. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking how to test deep equality using Chai.

[equal](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_equal):

> Asserts that the target is strictly (`===`) equal to the given `val`.
>
> ...
>
> Add `.deep` earlier in the chain to use deep equality instead.

[eql](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_eql):

> Asserts that the target is deeply equal to the given `obj`.

```js
mocha.setup('bdd');
const { expect } = chai;

describe('test', () => {
  it('fails', () => {
    expect({ a: 1 }).to.equal({ a: 1 });
  });

  it('passes', () => {
    expect({ a: 1 }).to.deep.equal({ a: 1 });
    expect({ a: 1 }).to.eql({ a: 1 });
  });
});

mocha.run();
```

```html
<div id="mocha" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mocha/8.0.1/mocha.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chai/4.2.0/chai.min.js"></script>
```

---

`.to.be.equal.to` is the same as `.equal`. The [language chains](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_language-chains) are optional:

> The following are provided as chainable getters to improve the readability of your assertions.